# Find $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}{\frac{1}{x}(\frac{1}{\sin(x)}-\frac{1}{\sinh(x)})}$.

Tags: analysis, limits, trigonometry

> $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}{\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{1}{\sin(x)}-\frac{1}{\sinh(x)}\right)}$$

I replaced $\sinh(x)$ by $\displaystyle\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}$ and used L'Hopital's rule twice but this expression becomes very large. 
Could you please help me

Comment: You can format maths in the title.

Comment: Use standard limits to reduce it to $(\sinh x-\sin x) /x^3$ and apply L'Hospital's Rule once and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Instead of using L'Hospital's Rule, we can apply Taylor's Theorem and obtain

$$\begin{align}
\frac1x\left(\frac{1}{\sin(x)}-\frac{1}{\sinh(x)}\right)&=\frac1x\left(\frac{\sinh(x)-\sin(x)}{\sin(x)\sinh(x)}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{\left(x+\frac16x^3+O(x^5)\right)-\left(x-\frac16x^3+O(x^5)\right)}{x^3+O(x^5)}
\end{align}$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: Can we do this without Taylor theorem or L-H rule ? maybe by using $\sin(ix) = i\sinh (x)$ ?

Comment: @A---B This approach seems quite efficient.  But see if your approach is better.  I don't see how it facilitates.

Comment: We did not introduce Taylor's Theorem in our lecture and thus i am not allowed to use it. Thats why your hint didn't help me much..
We introduced Eulers equation, and the identity: $\sinh(x)=-i\sin(it)$

Comment: @Valentin You have not covered Taylor's Theorem (or the extended mean-value theorem) yet?

Comment: @Dr. MV We introduced Taylor's Series for $\sinh(x)$ and $\sin(x)$

Comment: @Dr.MV I was just asking to see if we can solve this without LH or Taylor theorem. I like solving limits without those. I thought it would be better to ask if it is plausible before attempting on it.

Comment: @Valentin Great.  Then, you can see that $\sin(x)=x-\frac16x^3+\text{terms that are of order}\,5\,\text{or higher}$ and $\sinh(x)=x+\frac16x^3+\text{terms that are of order}\,5\,\text{or higher}$.  Can you make use of this?

Comment: @A---B It's possible I'm sure.  But it might be tedious.

Comment: @Dr.MV oh now i know what you mean with "O(5)". I will try it with this representation of $\sin(x)$ and $\sinh(x)$.

Comment: @Valentin Pleased to hear.  And [here is a link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) to an article on the "Big-O" notation.  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV Tanks alot! I got it now.

Comment: @Valentin You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark

Comment: And feel free to up vote and accept as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

write your term in the form $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sinh(x)-\sin(x)}{x\sin(x)\sinh(x)}$$ and use L'Hospital

Comment: Taking $3$ derivatives of the denominator is quite tedious at best.  This is highly inefficient as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of algebra:

$$\begin{align}
\frac1x\left(\frac{1}{\sin(x)}-\frac{1}{\sinh(x)}\right)&=\frac1x\left(\frac{\sinh(x)-\sin(x)}{\sin(x)\sinh(x)}\right)\\\\
&={x \over \sin x}{x \over \sinh x}{\sinh x -x+x-\sin x \over x^3}\\\\
&={x \over \sin x}{x \over \sinh x}\left ({\sinh x -x \over x^3}+{x-\sin x \over x^3}\right )
\end{align}$$

All the factors have a finite limit, so you can substitute each with its limit and find the answer you need.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: I am going to write the mother of overkills, just for fun.

From the Weierstrass product for the sine function we have
$$ \frac{x}{\sin(x)} = \prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2 n^2}\right)^{-1} = \prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{\pi^2 n^2}+\frac{x^4}{\pi^4 n^4}+\ldots\right) \tag{1}$$
and since $\frac{x}{\sin x}$ is an even analytic function in a neighbourhood of the origin we have
$$ \frac{x}{\sin(x)}=1+a_2 x^2+o(x^3),\qquad a_2 = \frac{1}{\pi^2}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\zeta(2)}{\pi^2}\tag{2} $$
and by replacing $x$ with $ix$ we also get
$$ \frac{x}{\sinh(x)}=1-a_2 x^2+o(x^3),\qquad a_2 = \frac{1}{\pi^2}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\zeta(2)}{\pi^2}\tag{3} $$
so:

$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{1}{\sin(x)}-\frac{1}{\sinh x}\right) = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}\left(\frac{x}{\sin(x)}-\frac{x}{\sinh x}\right) = 2a_2 = \color{red}{\frac{1}{3}}.\tag{4}$$

Comment: This is the father of overkills ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

for numerator,

$$\sinh (x )=x+\frac {x^3}{6}(1+\epsilon_1 (x)) $$

$$\sin (x)=x-\frac {x^3}{6}(1+\epsilon_2 (x)) $$

$$\sinh (x)-\sin (x)\sim \frac {2x^3}{6} (x\to 0) $$

your limit is $$\frac {1}{3} .$$

for denominator, use
$$\sin (x)\sim x (x\to 0) $$ and
$$\sinh (x)\sim x (x\to 0) $$

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{1}{\sin x}-\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{x}{\sin x}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}$$ is easy to evaluate.

Now you try 
$$\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{\sinh x}\right).$$